# Cannot import class from cython module

Tags: python, kivy, cython

I am trying to follow the tutorial for kivy on [PongBall](https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html)

, but VScode gives me error in line

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
```

with message:

> [pylint] E0611:No name 'NumericProperty' in module 'kivy.properties'
>
> [pylint] E0611:No name 'ReferenceListProperty' in module 'kivy.properties'

This module is I believe cython module and when I open the file `properties.pxd`
I can find following code:

```
...
cdef class NumericProperty(Property):
    cdef float parse_str(self, EventDispatcher obj, value)
    cdef float parse_list(self, EventDispatcher obj, value, ext)
...
cdef class ReferenceListProperty(Property):
    cdef list properties
    cpdef trigger_change(self, EventDispatcher obj, value)
    cpdef setitem(self, EventDispatcher obj, key, value)
...
```

Appendix:
this i the whole code so far:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector

class PongGame(Widget):
    pass

class PongBall(Widget):
    # velocity of the ball on x and y axis
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)

    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

Question:
Why it doesn't want to import and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You're not getting an error from Python, you're getting a warning from your linter. That doesn't affect running your code. IIRC, pylint doesn't work on Cython code without disabling almost all of the checks, so the usual answer is to just exclude Cython modules from linting. (I have no idea how to do that in VSCode's python plugin.)

Comment: I thought it does affect running because the window is just black. So you are saying that this is not the reason code is not running properly? I will check more, thanks!

Comment: I don't know where VSCode shows output, but if there's an actual error from running the code, that output window is going to say something starting with `ImportError` or `AttributeError`, not `[pylint] E0611`, and it should include a traceback (although in this case, the traceback probably won't be very useful—just one line of your code with a caret pointing at the name).

Comment: You were right. It wasn't this. It was actual error in code that was causing me problems. I probably accidentally pressed key and it threw everything off and there is no way to see if there was a error in this kv language from kivy framework. Thanks man!